# Website for Minecraft Server Wake Up on Lan

Tags: web, server, wake-on-lan

a friend of mine has a little server rig. He hosts a Minecraft-Server on it over his router at home. Because he doesn't wanna run it 24/7, I had an idea and I wanna ask if its possible.
My idea was to create a little website (world wide web) to start the server over wake up lan. I would run the website on my Rasperry Pie, which would be online 24/7.
Is that possible? If so, what should I learn to make the website safe, e.g. password?
Im not very familiar with website coding, but Im pretty good with software development with C-Based languages.
Im non-native speaker, so please excuse any grammar mistakes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wake on LAN works using broadcast packets, so in the local network only

And by default your router blocks those packets from the outside
You will have a bad time trying to make that works

In your case, the best choice would be to pay a little server online for your server

Comment: But what if i would start the sever over the website that runs on the rasperry pi that is connected over lan to the actual minecraft server?